# Best practice: Architecture for accounts with many locations 10k+

Tags: reporting, architecture, sales, parent-to-child, data-skew

I'm facing an architectural design where a company could have more than 10k locations, and I would like to save the location data, according to this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324399&type=1&mode=1) it's a good practice to use a hierarchical approach, where I have a parent Account (main company), and the child accounts as the different locations, for example:
The company Macdonald has several locations in the US, and I would like to represent in my Salesforce org the locations and the main company (parent). If I do the approach of using a parent account and child accounts (locations), then I could probably run into a [data skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_parent_child_data_skew.htm) problem.

What would be a good approach in this kind of situation?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How did you end up resolving this design?

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I have used in the past when facing data skewing problems is storing the ID to the parent record in a text field in the child record.

If you use that approach but still need a link from the child to the parent for your users, you can use a formula field to replicate the functionality provided by lookup fields.